# MongoDB slow read after first read

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to query a lot of documents (>100M) and I'm requesting them in batches of 5000 documents (~ 4-5MB each).
For some reason the first request (without `_id` filtering) returns quickly (~ 1.5s) while the
rest take significant time (~ 8-9.5s).

Now, when reading in batches of 500 documents (~ 500kB each) timing is significantly better (~ 0.5-0.8s) and is consistent for every request.

I'm using the `_id + limit` way of paginating as I saw that the `skip + limit` method performs much worse.

Here's a sample of my process.

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb")
var bytes = require("bytes")

...

var filter = {
    '_id': { '$gt': this._lastId }
}

if(mongodb.ObjectId.isValid(this._lastId)) {
    filter['_id'] = { '$gt': this._lastId }
}

var cursor = this.conn.collection(collectionName)
    .find(filter)
    .limit(5000)

var start = new Date().getTime()
cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) { ... }

    var elapsed = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000

    console.log(
        "Docs:", docs.length,
        "Size:", bytes(sizeof(docs)),
        "Took:", elapsed + " seconds"
    )

    var lastDoc = docs[docs.length - 1]

    this._lastId = lastDoc._id
})

...
```

Comment: a batch size between 250 and 500 will give you best result. batch of 5000 is too much and MongoDB driver will break it down to size of 1000 max internally.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem interesting, tried to reproduce it and came to the same results: the first call from id 0 to 5000 is fast and all the others are consistently longer (about 7x)

This is related to reading without filter. If you run your command in the mongo shell and do an explain on your find you'll see that no filter is applied when reading from 0 to 5000.

You can use the [.batchSize()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/#cursor.batchSize) to get more documents at a time (from your figures, each document is about 1KB). The default is 20 per cursor iteration.
When you run your .toArray() function it will send chunks of 20KB from MongoDB to your application until the 5000 docs are transferred. It might be more optimised to use bigger batches, you should try different values but I would start with 500 to get 500KB at a time as it reduce the network overhead of little chunks.
You might also find that [cursor.forEach()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) works better as it transfers the data as it gets processed (by chunks of batchSize(n)). In this case it does not matter much if you query the whole collection or chunks of 5000 if at the end you want to inspect ALL documents.

A cursor leaves a connection open and allocate resources on the MongoDB server until you close the cursor or the connection to the DB but the cursor does not grow in size it just holds the data of the batch.

On a side note, I would argue that doing smaller batches is not faster: time per doc is similar, 10 times less documents is about 10 times faster.

Comment: I realized the same thing for the smaller batches, but smaller batches might play more nicelly with the system's memory. Can you elaborate on the use of `cursor.batchSize()`? I'm less familiar with it. It keeps an open connection until it's exhausted right? for 100M+ documents that can take a whole lotta time.